# Extract date and time from a natural language string

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, date-and-time, text, regular-expressions

Is there a way to robustly extract date and time from a text? Say for example:

> ...The event will be held on 17/10/2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and
> everyone is welcome...

should return:

> ```
> {2013, 10, 17, 15, 30, 0}
> ```

The emphasis here is on **robustness of the extraction**. The same output is expected when the date is slightly twisted as follows:

> ...The event will be held on 17th October 2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and ...
>
> ...The event will be held on October 17th 2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and ...
>
> ...The event will be held on 17 October 2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and ...

I guess this is a fairly trivial problem in natural language processing, though I am not aware of the state-of-the-art. I think simple regular expressions are the way to go. Is there an existing resource that can do this?

Comment: PHP has a very neat function, strtotime, that will interpret strings. It is very robust because it has a large list of different patterns that it matches. These patterns are available here: http://se1.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: Nice find! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
string="The event will be held on 7/10/2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and \
everyone is welcome";
```

extract the date and time:

```
dateTime=StringCases[string, ___ ~~ 
   x : DatePattern[{"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year", " at ", "Hour", 
      ":", "Minute", " ", "AMPM"}] ~~ ___ :> x]

(*  {"7/10/2013 at 3:30 PM"}  *)
```

Make into a date list

```
DateList[{First@dateTime, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year", " at ", 
   "Hour", ":", "Minute", " ", "AMPM"}}]

(*  {2013, 7, 10, 15, 30, 0.}  *)
```

You can do the same for the other examples by changing the date pattern.

**Edit**

or just create your date pattern list:

```
pattern = {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year", " at ", "Hour", ":", 
  "Minute", " ", "AMPM"}
```

then:

```
dateTime = StringCases[string, ___ ~~ x : DatePattern[pattern] ~~ ___ :> x];
DateList[{First@dateTime, pattern}]

(*  {2013, 7, 10, 15, 30, 0.}  *)
```

Comment: Just a minor point...the datetime format is non US in example  so `pattern={"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year", " at ", "Hour", ":", "Minute", " \
", "AMPM"} will extract the correct October not July date. Also, `DateList[{StringCases[string, DatePattern[pattern]][[1]], pattern}]` works

Comment: @ubpdqn thanks. I'll fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
str1="...The event will be held on 17/10/2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and everyone is welcome...";
str2="...The event will be held on 17th October 2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and ...";
str3="...The event will be held on October 17th 2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and ...";
str4="...The event will be held on 17 October 2013 at 3:30 PM in the room 121 and ...";
Normal[Dataset[TextCases[#, {"Date", "Time"}] & /@ {str1, str2, str3, str4}][
   All, {"Date" -> DateObject@*First, "Time" -> TimeObject@*Last}][All, Values]]
```

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? I am using 12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `TextCases`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
str1 = "The event will be held on 17/10/2013 at 3:30 PM in the room \
121 and everyone is welcome.";
str2 = "The event will be held on 17th October 2013 at 3:30 PM in the \
room 121.";
str3 = "The event will be held on October 17th 2013 at 3:30 PM in the \
room 121";
str4 = "The event will be held on 17 October 2013 at 3:30 PM in the \
room 121";

strs = {str1, str2, str3, str4};

parseDateTime[s_String] := Module[{d, t},
  d = DateObject @@ First@Values@TextCases[# , {"Date"}] &@s;
  t = First@
     StringCases[s, 
      "at" ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ 
        k : (DigitCharacter .. ~~ ":" ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ 
           Whitespace ... ~~ "am" | "AM" | "pm" | "PM" ) :> k] // 
    TimeObject;
  Join[{d, t}] // Apply[DateObject] // DateList
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

```
parseDateTime@str1
```

> {2013, 10, 17, 15, 30, 0.}

```
parseDateTime /@ strs
```

> {{2013, 10, 17, 15, 30, 0.}, {2013, 10, 17, 15, 30, 0.}, {2013, 10,
> 17, 15, 30, 0.}, {2013, 10, 17, 15, 30, 0.}}

Comment: Why don't use "Time"?

Comment: `TextCases` doesn't seem to have the "Time" parsing option. Using the interpreter makes it very slow. @yode.